# launch ie and save the page

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, powershell

I need to launch IE, browse to many different sites and save the pages that I browse to. Can .net work with IE like this or is a script a better approach?

Comment: What do you mean by Save the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to save the page do something like this. Here you get that html, not a screen shot of the page.

```
    string url = "http://google.com";
    string strResult = "";
    WebResponse objResponse;
    WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        // Close and clean up the StreamReader
        sr.Close();
    }
    // Display results to a webpage
    //Response.Write(strResult);
    Console.WriteLine(strResult);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

If you need a picture of the page use something like autoit or watin.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) Class for this. You can load the site and then you can use its event handlers to save the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is too complicated. If you really just need to download the source html, use this function:

```
function Download-Page([string]$url) {
  $w = New-Object net.webclient
  $w.DownloadString($url)
}
```

Then you can save the content like this:

```
Download-Page http://www.google.com | Set-Content d:\google.html
```

(this will work with localhost urls as well)